# Is it a security hole to have a stored procedure output the key and certificate names?

Tags: certificates, key-management, sql-server

**My scenario is this:**

(Following the method of opening keys, encrypting, and closing keys, found in [Ben Cull's Blog](http://benjii.me/2010/05/how-to-use-sql-server-encryption-with-symmetric-keys/).)

Imagine you have a MS SQL sever with tons of keys for encrypting different fields in different tables which you update every so often, and you use procedures to open the keys and close the keys, BUT in order to reduce the number of procedures and functions you have to update every so often, you eliminate the functions to encrypt the data, and you instead `OUTPUT` the key and certificate names, so you can just use the regular encrypt function with the key and certificate from the OUTPUT parameters of the OpenKey procedure.

It would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sproc_OpenKey_10]
    (
        @Key CHAR(10) OUTPUT
        ,@Cert CHAR(10) OUTPUT
    )
AS 
BEGIN

    IF CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())  < '1/1/2017'
        BEGIN
            OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AC_16
            DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE WebAC16
            Set @Key = 'AC_16'
            Set @Cert = 'WebAC16'
        END
    ELSE    
        BEGIN
            OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AC_17
            DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE WebAC17
            Set @Key = 'AC_17'
            Set @Cert = 'WebAC17'
        END
    RETURN
END
```

And so using the function and encrypting would look like this:

```
DECLARE @Key10 CHAR(10)
DECLARE @Cert10 CHAR(10)
DECLARE @EncID VARCHAR(100)

EXEC dbo.sproc_Secure_OpenKey_10 @Key = @Key10 OUTPUT, @Cert = @Cert10 OUTPUT   
SET @EncID = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID(@Key10), @Custid)
```

(NOTE: the cert would be stored in the table for decryption later --that is why it would be returned.)

In theory, this would be handy, allowing you to only have to update the OpenKey and CloseKey procedures.

**My question is:**

Is outputting the Key and Cert names from an OpenKey stored procedure a possible security hole? If so, is there a way to make this secure?

I'll appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time and research, I think I've answered my own question.

When using this method of opening and closing keys, you don't set any permissions, therefore nothing that doesn't already have the appropriate permissions (of its own) can use the stored procedure and receive the outputted Key and Cert names --the OpenKey and CloseKey stored procedures work under the permissions of the calling stored procedure, therefore only the calling stored procedure with the permissions will be able to use and see the Key and Cert names outputted by the OpenKey procedure.

**In summary:** it seems outputting the Key and Cert names in the OpenKey stored procedure should not create a security hole, provided no permissions are set for it.

I thought I'd share my findings, if perhaps it would help someone else.